# Excel: Add number before multiplying with PRODUCT(...)

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I am calculating the geometric mean of a row in MS Excel by using the `GEOMEAN(...)` command.

**What is the geometric mean**: The row could be `A1:A10`. A geometric mean with

```
 GEOMEAN(A1:A10)
```

is the product of all 10 cell values (multiplied together) after which the 10th root is taken (mathematically: `nth_root(A_1 x A_2 x ... x A_n)` ).

**The issue**: The command `GEOMEAN(A1:A10)` works fine as long as no cells contain negative values (actually just as long as the product ends up positive). If one cell has a negative value, then taking the root is mathematically an invalid action and Excel gives an error.

**The solution:** I can work-around this by adding a large enough number such as `+1000000` to each value before doing `GEOMEAN(A1:A10)` and afterwards subtracting `-1000000` from the result. This is a mathematical approximation to the pure geometrical mean.

**The question:** But how do I add `+1000000` to each value in Excel? A solution would be to create a whole new extra row where the number is added, and then doing `GEOMEAN` on this row and subtracting the number from the result. But I would really like to avoid creating a new row, since I have many long data sets to perform this command on.

Is there a way to add the number inside the command itself? To add it onto each value before it is multiplied? Something along the lines of:

```
GEOMEAN(A1:A10+1000000)-1000000
```

### Solution to avoid the work-around

*Based on the answer from and discussion with @ImaginaryHuman072889*

It turns out that a working command that avoids any work-around is:

```
 IFERROR(GEOMEAN(A1:A10);-GEOMEAN(ABS(A1:A10)))
```

If an error are cought by the `IFERROR`, then we know that a negative result would have appeared, so this is constructed manually in that case.

**BUT**: This does not take into account the case mentioned by @ImaginaryHuman072889, though, because Excel seems to forbid any negative numbers involved and not just if the inner product is negative. For example, both `GEOMEAN(-2,-2)` as well as `GEOMEAN(-2,-2,-2)` give errors in Excel, even though they both should be mathematically valid, giving the results `2` and `-2`, respectively. To overcome this Excel-issue, we can simply write out the exact same command line manually:

```
 IFERROR(PRODUCT(A1:A10)^(1/COUNTA(A1:A10));-(PRODUCT(ABS(A1:A10))^(1/COUNTA(A1:A10)))))
```

I add this solution to aid any by-comers who have the same issue. This mathematically works, but the fact that `-2` and `-2` have the geometrical mean `2` does seem a bit odd and not at all like any useful value of a "mean". It is still mathematically legal as far as I can find ([WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=geometric%20mean%20of%20-2%20and%20-2) has no issue with it and the Wikipedia article never mentions a sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "workaround" of doing this:

```
GEOMEAN(A1:A10+1000000)-1000000
```

Is **completely wrong**. This is absolutely not equal to `GEOMEAN(A1:A10)`.

Simple counter-example:

`GEOMEAN({2,8})` returns the value of 4, which is the geometric mean of 2 and 8.

`GEOMEAN({2,8}+1)-1` is equal to `GEOMEAN({3,9})-1` which is approximately 4.196.

What *is* a valid workaround is if you multiply each value inside `GEOMEAN` by a certain value, then divide the result by that value.

Simple example:

`GEOMEAN({2,8}*3)/3` is equal to `GEOMEAN({6,24})/3` which is 4.

However, this method of multiplying by a constant does not help your situation, since this won't get rid of negative values.

Mathematically speaking, the geometric mean of a positive number and a negative number is an imaginary number, which is presumably why Excel cannot handle it.

Example:

```
2*-8 = -16

sqrt(-16) = 4i
```

Therefore, 4i is the geometric mean of 2 and -8. Notice how it has the same *magnitude* as `GEOMEAN({2,8})`, just that it is an imaginary number.

All that said... here is what I recommend you doing:

I suggest you return *two* results, one result is the **magnitude** of the geometric mean and the other is the **phase** of the geometric mean.

Formula for magnitude:

```
= GEOMEAN(ABS(A1:A10))
```

(Note, this is an array formula, so you'd have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula.) The use of `ABS` converts all negative numbers to positive before the `GEOMEAN` calculation, guaranteeing a positive geometric mean.

Formula for phase, I would just do something like this:

```
= IF(PRODUCT(A1:A10)>=0,"Real","Imaginary")
```

Which obviously returns `Real` if the geometric mean is a real number and returns `Imaginary` if the geometric mean is an imaginary number.

---

**EDIT**

Technically speaking, some of what I said wasn't completely precise, although the magnitude formula above still stands.

Some things I want to clarify:

1. If `PRODUCT(data)` is *positive* (or zero), then the geometric mean of `data` is *positive* (or zero).
2. If `PRODUCT(data)` is *negative* **and** if the number of entries in `data` is *odd*, then the geometric mean of `data` is *negative* (but still *real*).
3. If `PRODUCT(data)` is *negative* **and** if the number of entries in `data` is *even*, then the geometric mean of `data` is *imaginary*.

That said... if you want these formulas to be a bit more technically accurate, I would modify to this:

Adjusted formula for magnitude:

```
= GEOMEAN(ABS(A1:A10))*IF(AND(PRODUCT(A1:A10)<0,MOD(COUNT(A1:A10),2)=1),-1,1)
```

Adjusted formula for phase:

```
= IF(AND(PRODUCT(A1:A10)<0,MOD(COUNT(A1:A10),2)=0),"Imaginary","Real")
```

If the geometric mean is real, it returns the precise geometric mean (whether it is positive or negative), and if the geometric mean is imaginary, it returns a positive real value with the correct magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and I do realize that my work-around here will not give the same value as the pure geometrical mean. I have edited the question to fit this fact. I have asked a [question on the mathematical aspect here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544279/geometric-mean-on-negative-numbers-work-around) to understand this deviation. Your suggestion of the imaginary result is interesting- will the magnitude of the imaginary number *always* equal the equivalent real value? If so, then I don't even need a workaround - I can just use your absolute-value-method.

Comment: @Steeven Correct. The magnitude is always exact, not an approximation. The only difference is that it is imaginary instead of real.

Comment: @Steeven Actually, that is only partially correct. It is also possible that the geographic mean is purely negative (but not imaginary). In the trivial example `GEOMEAN({-2,-2,-2})`, the geographic mean is -2. Still, the magnitude formula is unaffected.

Comment: The geometrical mean is not defined for a negative inner product. `GEOMEAN({-2,-2,-2})` gives an error.

Comment: @Steeven I meant purely in a mathematical sense, not in terms of the Excel function. In other words, what I meant was: `(-2*-2*-2)^(1/3) = -2`.

Comment: @Steeven You're welcome. I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I have added a solution that avoids the work-around (similar to the edit you just added to your answer) to the question based on your answer and our discussion here. Thank you for the talk.

Comment: @Steeven See my answer. Formula has been edited to return negative real geometric mean if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just found the answer - although I have no idea why this works.

Doing `GEOMEAN(A1:A10+1000000)-1000000` is actually possible. But by pressing `enter` and error `#VALUE` is displayed. You must click `control+shift+enter` to have the actual result displayed.

According to this: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/264366-calculating-geometric-mean-some-negative-values.html

If anyone has an explanation for this, I am very interested.

Comment: by using control+shift+enter you enter an array formula. This means that the calculation (A1:A10+1000000) is performed for each cell separately before GEOMEAN is calculated. array formulas are quite useful for example when you want to sum or multiply columns line by line which is essentially what it does in your formula.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @Pavel_V. I do not see the usefulness in Excel when it doesn't automatically do an array calculation instead of showing an error.

Comment: In your case it is the only solution to use array formula, but there are cases in which you can use both for the same text entered and the standard formula and array formula will give you different result. So excel cant simpy assume which is entered, because it would be definitely wrong sometimes. Also array formulas take quite long to recalculate - in my work files (hundereds thousands if lines) it can take really long time compared to standard formulas so it is safer to have to specify that something is array formula I guess.

Comment: @Pavel_V I see. Thank you for the clarification.